# ExtJS event delegation not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have the following function, which I am trying to execute with the default values.

```
init: function(userConfig) {
    var config = {};
    Ext.apply(config, userConfig, {
         delegate: 'div.thumbnailNameProfileListingItem span'
    });

    Ext.getBody().on({
        scope: this,
        click: function(a, b, c, d, e) {
           console.log(a);
        },
        delegate: config.delegate
    });
}
init();
```

When I click on the DOM element denoted by the default value of the "delegate" property, the function provided to "click" does not get called. The elements do not yet exist in the DOM at this point, they are added later by another user-triggered event.

However when I change the value of the "delegate" property from

```
delegate: 'div.thumbnailNameProfileListingItem span'
```

to

```
delegate: 'span'
```

the function gets called for both existing and later added DOM elements. Is there a limitation in the use of delegation in ExtJS in that it doesn't allow selectors spanning between parent and children elements or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `on()` right? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-on says that you need to pass bunch of parameters not just an object.

Comment: Yes. But just to make sure I tried passing them as function arguments instead and it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't solve the problem, so I decided to reduce the selector in the "delegate" property to this:

```
delegate: 'span.profileItemClick'
```

It does the job.